Oracle fetchmany() , fetchall() , arraysize() and executemany()
I wanted to know the difference between using the following function
fetchmany() , fetchall() , arraysize() and executemany()
How my result will change,  while using either

All covered in great detail here
https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-The-New-Wave-of-Scripting.html
but in a nutshell
Given a cursor opened with query: SELECT * FROM MY_1000_ROW_TABLE
fetchone - get the first/next row
fetchmany - get a batch of rows, the batch being 'arraysize' in size.
executemany - similar, but with an update/delete/etc. You are passing a batch of rows back to the database in one trip for efficiency

Also see the python-oracledb user documentation on Fetch Methods.
